# How to render an webViewLink provided by google drive api in a HTMLElement as img?

Tags: google-drive-api

I was able to get a webViewLink provided by google drive api, but I don't kwon how I can proceed with that.
Tried a lot to render the webViewLink in some HTMLElements like img, iframes, and a keep, but no success.

I tried render in some HTMLElements, but it didn't work